# Creating a findable shared library with cmake

Tags: cmake

I am rewriting libraries from hand-written Makefiles to using cmake. I am getting stuck at the point where I need to library library A from library B.

I can find the libraries using find_package, but when they are being linked cmake complains about not having a rule for building the .so file because it is looking for it in the *build directory* instead of the installed directory.

This is explained if I look at the /usr/lib/cmake/library/libraryConfigVersion.cmake file, which contains this hardcoded path. This file was created with the following steps:

```
write_basic_package_version_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libraryConfigVersion.cmake"
    VERSION ${LIBRARY_VERSION}
    COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

export(EXPORT libraryTargets
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/library/libraryConfigVersion.cmake"
    NAMESPACE library::
)
```

(i have replaced my library name with 'library'). How can I get cmake to write the correct path so that I can easily link against my library from other cmake projects?

Answer (score 0):

Command [export](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/export.html) actually exports *build tree*. This is explicitely written in the documentation.

For **export install tree**, use `install(TARGETS ... EXPORT)` plus `install(EXPORT)`. Both flows are described in documentation for [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/install.html) command.

See also CMake tutorial [Exporting and Importing Targets](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets).